# Comparing multiple columns from the same file

Tags: bash, awk

I want to compare multiple columns from the same file to see in which line I have differences, in this case, the first 4 columns. The file looks like this:

```
           Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
              AA      AA      AA      AA    AA
              GG      GG      GG      GG    GG
              CC      GC      CC      CC    CC
              CC      TT      CC      GC    TT
```

If I did something like this:

```
 awk -F"\t" '{if ($1==$2) print $1, $2; else print NR}' file.txt
```

I get the next output:

```
             1
             AA      AA 
             GG      GG 
             4
             5
```

But, How I could compare the first 4 columns at the same time with a simple syntaxis? I tried something like this:

```
       awk -F"\t" '{if ([$2,$3,$4]==$1) print $1, $2, $3, $4 ; else print NR}' File.txt
```

but it is not working.

My expected output should be:

```
              1 
              AA      AA      AA      AA
              GG      GG      GG      GG
              4
              5
```

My file has more than four columns, so I want to compare groups of columns, in this case from column 1 to 4, and print only these four columns if they have the same characters, or the number of the row if they have differences.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Please mention the expected output in your post too.

Comment: Done, thanks for the advice.

Comment: It's not clear - are you trying to print rows which have the same value in every column or are you trying to print rows that have the same value in all columns as other rows or something else? What are those numbers in the output?

Comment: I am trying to print the 4 columns if they have the same characters, if they don't have the same caharcters,  I want to print the row number.

Comment: @EricGonzález is the whitespace at start of each line part of your input file or just formatting trouble you have while posting the data?

Comment: also, if a line has `AT AT AT AT`, what should be the output?

Comment: The white space is not part of the table, just the columns.

Comment: just for fun: for given sample, you could use GNU sed as well `sed -nE 's/^(([^\t]+)(\t\2){3}).*/\1/p; t; ='` or `perl -lne 'print /^([^\t]+)(\t\1){3}/ ? $& : $.'` .. would need adjustments to avoid partial match in 4th column(but given 2 character field data, perhaps not needed), but not easy to modify for generic columns processing

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a loop to step through your columns:

```
$ awk '{x=0;for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if($i!=$(i+1)){x=1}} print x?NR:$0}' input.txt
```

Or, for easier reading:

```
{
  x=0                     # initialize the flag for each line
  for (i=1;i<NF;i++) {    # step through the fields
    if ($i!=$(i+1)) {     # test for a match with the next field
      x=1                 # and set a flag if we see different content.
    }
  }
  print x ? NR : $0       # print NR or the first field depending on flag value
}
```

This steps through all fields (not just four) comparing the content of each field to the content of the field after it. If at any time the fields don't match, a flag is set.

The ternary operator in the final statement selects which output to show based on the flag.

Note that your expected output appears to have whitespace trimmed from the beginning of the line. If you really want this, you can `sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")` before the `print` statement.

Comment: You might want to change `$i!=` to `($i"")!=` so that `5.0` won't be considered the same as `5` or `005`. I'm just assuming the OP wants string instead of numeric comparisons in that situation. Btw, some awks will fail with a syntax error given an unparenthesized ternary expression in some contexts (OSX/BSD awk in particular comes to mind) so it's best to always parenthesize them, e.g. `print (x ? NR : $0)`, - even when not strictly necessary it improves readability anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much. If my file have more than 4 columns, and I want to compare only from column 1 to column 4, and print only that four columns if we have a match or the number of row if I don´t have a match. How I could do it?

Comment: Step 1 would be posting a question/example about THAT instead of the question/example you posted where you want to compare all columns.

Comment: My  apologies, I edit the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk '{
    sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")
    delete uniq
    for (i=1;i<=4;i++) {
        uniq[$i]
        out=(i>1 ? out OFS : "") $i
    }
    print (length(uniq) > 1 ? NR : out)
}' file
1
AA AA AA AA
GG GG GG GG
4
5
```

That requires an awk that gets the number of elements in an array with `length(array)` which GNU awk can, I'm not sure about others.

Assuming you do have an awk that supports `length(array)` then whether you do it this way or use [@ghoti's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51880025/1745001) of comparing adjacent values only matters if you at some point need a count of unique values (which only mine provides) rather than just a yes/no on whether there's 1 or more than 1 unique values (which both provide). For example if you wanted to print how many unique values were present in each row that isn't all unique after printing the row number:

```
awk '{
    sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")
    delete uniq
    for (i=1;i<=4;i++) {
        uniq[$i]
        out=(i>1 ? out OFS : "") $i
    }
    numUniq = length(uniq)
    print (numUniq > 1 ? NR OFS numUniq : out)
}' file
1 4
AA AA AA AA
GG GG GG GG
4 2
5 3
```

btw if you're using an awk that doesn't support `length(array)` you can write your own:

```
function alength(a, i,c) {for (i in a) ++c; return c+0}
```

and just call it as `alength(array)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an associative array, and increase the count of each value as you do a linear pass. You can simply:

```
$ awk '{delete x; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) x[$i]++; if (x[$NF]==NF) print $0; else print NR;}' file.txt
1
AA AA AA AA
GG GG GG GG
4
5
```